# Force newline in concepts

Tags: line-breaking, two-column, acm, xml, css

I am following this [acm-template](http://www.acm.org/publications/article-templates/proceedings-template.html/) (Zip set of TeX template files for easy download (May, 2015).) I have this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002951.10003227.10003351.10003445</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Information systems~Nearest-neighbor search</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10003752.10003809.10010055.10010060</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Theory of computation~Nearest neighbor algorithms</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>

</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Information systems~Nearest-neighbor search}
\ccsdesc[500]{Theory of computation~Nearest neighbor algorithms}
\printccsdesc
\end{document}
```

I need to force a newline after the first concept, so that Theory computation starts from the next line. How to make this happen?

---

Attempt:

```
\ccsdesc[500]{Information systems~Nearest-neighbor search\newline}
\ccsdesc[500]{Theory of computation~Nearest neighbor algorithms}
```

However, this will produce a newline, but will leave a trailing `;` for the next line.

Comment: have you tried to insert a <br>?

Comment: No @naphaneal, where?

Comment: at the point you wish to have a newline.

Comment: I tried between the `concept` tags, but no result @naphaneal.

Comment: please provide a full MWE. I'd like to test something

Comment: @naphaneal updated, thank you for your time. Maybe an upvote could bring more people to help, since that's tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want *every* new concept to start at a new line, you can do like this.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ccsdesc@parse}{\textbullet}{\par\noindent\textbullet}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002951.10003227.10003351.10003445</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Information systems~Nearest-neighbor search</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10003752.10003809.10010055.10010060</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Theory of computation~Nearest neighbor algorithms</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>

</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Information systems~Nearest-neighbor search}
\ccsdesc[500]{Theory of computation~Nearest neighbor algorithms}

\printccsdesc
\end{document}
```

[image]

A horrible hack for just placing a new line command before the second item:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand\HH{% horrible hack
  \global\let\savedtextbullet\textbullet
  \gdef\textbullet{%
    \par\noindent\savedtextbullet\global\let\textbullet\savedtextbullet
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002951.10003227.10003351.10003445</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Information systems~Nearest-neighbor search</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10003752.10003809.10010055.10010060</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Theory of computation~Nearest neighbor algorithms</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>

</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Information systems~Nearest-neighbor search\HH}
\ccsdesc[500]{Theory of computation~Nearest neighbor algorithms}
\ccsdesc[500]{Nothing particular~Just for testing}
\printccsdesc
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: egreg, thanks, that works, but your assumption is wrong (and I am the one to blame). In practice I have more concepts and I would like to force the newline only for the 2nd one. However, if that is much work for you, let me know, so that I can accept. :)

Comment: @gsamaras I'm not sure whether this is sensible. Are these “concepts” used elsewhere in the document?

Comment: much easier: remove the `-` from `Neighbor-nearest search`. though @egreg answer is more smexy

Comment: No. However, I need to change line only for the 2nd concept (which overlaps with the right column in a two-columned paper I am writing). The other concepts do not have a reason to be flushed in a newline.

Comment: @naphaneal I would suggest you to provide a separate answer, if you have one. :)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat less horrible hack looks like this:

```
\def\NL#1{#1\hfil\break}

...
\ccsdesc[500]{Information systems~Nearest-neighbor search\NL}
\ccsdesc[500]{Theory of computation~Nearest neighbor algorithms}
\ccsdesc[500]{Nothing particular~Just for testing}
```